# roots of cubic equations and vietas relations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

> [image: Here is the Question]

I tried using Vieta's relations and substituting $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 0$, but I haven't got anywhere so far.

Comment: $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_transformation#Transformation_by_a_rational_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

$$y=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$$ then

$$x=\frac{y-1}{y+1}.$$

Hence the equation

$$\left(\frac{y-1}{y+1}\right)^3-\left(\frac{y-1}{y+1}\right)^2-1=0$$ has the roots $\dfrac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha},\cdots$

The numerator of the above rational function is

$$-y^3-5y^2+y-3$$

hence the answer

$$-5$$ by Vieta.

Answer (score 3):

Since $x^3-x^2-1=0$, we have $\frac 1{x-1}=x^2$, then:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}+\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}+\frac{1+\gamma}{1-\gamma}
&=-(\alpha^2+\alpha^3+\beta^2+\beta^3+\gamma^2+\gamma^3)\\
&=-(\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3+\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2)\\\\
\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3&=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^3-3(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma)+3\alpha\beta\gamma\\\\
\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2&=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2-2(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma)
\end{align*}

Then you can just plug in the Vieta formula and get the answer.